# Creating OneNote file using MS Graph API similar to file creation in MS Teams

Tags: onenote-api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I want to create OneNote file using MS Graph API. functionality should be same as creating OneNote file in Teams channel
as in below Image, I created OneNote file from ***Documents> Genaral>Folder One*** location.
But I couldn't do same thing from graph api

[image]

I tried this [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{SITE_ID}/onenote/notebooks](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BSITE_ID%7D/onenote/notebooks) graph api .
but it doesn't have way to indicate folder name and also it creates OneNote file under folder called 'Notebooks'

is thee way to accomplish this using  graph api ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your deriving the API call from the [**Create notebook page**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-post-notebooks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

You can then use OneDrive/Sharepoint end points to move the Notebook from the **Notebooks** folder to the **Documents> Genaral>Folder One** location.
As described on [**Get a DriveItem resource page**](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get?view=odsp-graph-online) get the "driveId" ("sited" also appears to work) and "id" of the notebook and the "id" of the destination folder using a call such as 
`GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/root:/{item-path}`
**[Move a DriveItem to a new folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_move?view=odsp-graph-online)** end point to complete the process

```
PATCH /drives/{driveid}/items/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "parentReference": {
    "id": "{destination-folder-id}"
  },
  "name": "Notebook1"
}
```